# understanding an identity with the prime counting function

Tags: number-theory

we know from complex number theory that the Chebyshev function

$$ \Psi (x) = x- \sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}+r(x)$$

where $ r(x) $ is a remainder

then we also know that $$ \int _{1}^{x}dQ(x)\log(x) =  \Psi (x) $$

but what i do not know is the last identity

$$ Q(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \pi (x^{1/n}) $$

for the prime number counting function

Comment: This isn't a question, as stated. Are you looking for a reference to the definition of $Q(x)$? A proof of the middle line, given the definition? A proof of the last line, given the middle line? ...

Comment: the chebyshev functions runs over primes and prime powers $ p^{m} $ with m=1,2,3,4,........ then shouldn't we have only  $ Q(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \pi (x^{1/n})= $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Lambda(k)$ does not equal $\log k$ on prime powers; instead, $\Lambda(p^m) = \log p = \frac1m \log(p^m)$, or in other words, $\Lambda(k) = \frac1m\log k$ when $k$ is the $m$th power of a prime. That's where the $\frac 1n$ comes from in the definition of $Q(x)$ ($m$ and $n$ are playing the same role here).